# How long will a power supply last?

Tags: power-supply

I have a 5 year old desktop that is still going strong. I replaced its video card, harddrive and cpu fan. I always figured that once I either get a decent amount of income, hardware requirements went up or it got "too old", I would just replace it. This thing works fine though, is fast, multitasks, plays games on highest settings, all that and it seems like I may not have to replace it.....except for the power supply. How long do you think it could last? I don't want my PSU blowing up and erasing my data randomly one day.

This happens to be mine:

http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817139007

Comment: This entirely depends on the individual product expected lifespan.  Do you have a specific question we can answer?  Since we can't predict how long a random PSU will last?

Comment: I am sure there is an average or some sort of standard?

Comment: Some PSU have a warranty of 10 years, some have a warranty of a year, you can estimate the expected lifespan based on the length of the product's warranty.

Comment: My experience has been they usually last until you overload them, but my experience is exclusively with classic switching supplies; "active" units may be prone to failures I haven't experienced.

Comment: Corsair gives that line a 5 year warranty. That is as good a guess as you are likely to get. But it is still a guess...

Comment: "I don't want my PSU blowing up and erasing my data randomly one day." This won't happen, but if it did, there is just as much chance of it happening with a "new" PSU.  Afraid of data loss?  Make regular backups. ;)

Comment: @user3452783 I think that replacing something simply on age isn't a good way to go at it especially with a PSU. For the most part PSUs haven't really changed that much in many years. If you are not close to exceeding the recommended wattage requirements and it has all the correct plugs for what you need there is no reason to replace it.  Like Techie007 said, there is no added risk of it "blowing up" compared to a new one.

Comment: Yeah, overload as in too much power being drawn? This thing is 1,000 watts and I don't plan on going SLI. Even with my power hungry gtx 760 gpu, I don't think it'll  be too taxing.

Comment: @user3452783 Then no real point to upgrade unless you like to donate money to Newegg :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That spesific PSU you listed has a 5 year warranty, so id estimate the lifespan of it (in a gaming rig that does not overload it) to be a few years over warranty.

With Electronic equipment its very hard to judge lifespan, but it can exceed the warranty , and possibly most folks expectations when its been looked after.

My PSU has lasted for about 9 years now and it still hasnt acted out yet.

Comment: What model psu do you have?